# Is it possible to drag and drop a button on a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a button and a textbox in the same form. Is it possible to drag the button and drop it on a textbox (white space)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Why would you do that?

Comment: I think textbox can only contain text

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that.

All you need to do is add the `Button` or any other `Control` to the `TextBox`'s `Controls` collection or, with a little less typing, make the `TextBox` the `Parent` of the `Button`.

Here is an example without dragging&dropping:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Parent = textBox1;
    button1.Location = Point.Empty;
}
```

Before and after:

[image][image]

As you can see it will overlay the `Text` and you will want to set the `Location` to a better value. Finding a good spot is up to you!

So if you **really** want to you **can** do it.

Adapting the code to drag&drop is not really different from any other case of d&d. There is  even a [little example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za0zx9y0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that shows exactly the case of dragging a `Button` onto a `TextBox` but with the aim to put the `Button.Text` there.

Note that the example is not only a little silly but also fails to mention that the way they do it, namely by starting the d&d in the `MouseDown`, the `Button` can no longer be **clicked**!

Here is the corrected example:

```
private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.AllowedEffect & DragDropEffects.Link) != 0
      && e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Button)))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
}

private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button)) as Button;
    btn.Parent = textBox1;
    btn.Location = new Point(textBox2.Width - btn.Width - 2, -2);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "The Button is still working!";
}

// we use the MouseMove with a check for the left button
private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
       DoDragDrop((sender as Button), DragDropEffects.Link); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Taw. Please what can I do if I want to be able to write in the textbox area after the button. I mean I don't want the dropped button to hide a text.

Comment: Well it will take up __some__ space so you best make the textbox large enough and place the button to the right like the second piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. You can create a `UserControl` which houses both the controls but you simply cannot put one control inside another.